# mkinitcpio -p linux /usr/bin/mkinicpio: line 265: /etc/mkinicpio.d/linux.preset: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, archlinux

при установке arch linux   [по этому туториалу](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=METZCp_JCec)

при вводе комманды mkinitcpio -p linux выдает ошибку /usr/bin/mkinicpio: line 265: /etc/mkinicpio.d/linux.preset: no such file or directory  Fail to load preset

Comment: Устанавливать rolling-дистрибутив по уроку **шестилетней** давности — это ОЧЕНЬ хреновая идея. За прошедшее время поменялось примерно всё

Comment: andreymal что эта вообще за команда можно ли её пропустить ?

Comment: Нельзя, потому что она собирает initramfs-образ, с которого обязательно начинается загрузка любого линукса. Однако [официальная документация](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) гласит, что в 2020 году mkinitcpio выполняется автоматически после pacstrap, так что видимо запускать её вручную необязательно

Comment: Тем не менее она должна отрабатывать нормально, так что, вы, видимо, запускаете её в live-образе и перед запуском команды забыли сделать arch-chroot (на видео 8:03)

Comment: andreymal то есть всё таки имеет смысл пропустить этот шаг и продолжить установку загрузчика?ничего я не забыл я под рутом

Comment: может пресет где то в другом месте теперь леит?

Comment: Нет, в том же самом. Я всё ещё думаю, что вы забыли включить chroot перед выполнением команды

Comment: andreymal да вводил я arch-chroot /mnt

Comment: Можно предположить, что могли случайно выйти после этого, и если всё-таки вышли, то значит надобно вводить заново, чтобы вернуться в chroot

Comment: andreymal ты ну я не совсем дибил, я же вижу что я сижу под рутом и в корневом каталоге

Comment: Ну так без chroot тоже будет рут в корневом каталоге (только корневым каталогом будет каталог из livecd). Вы в курсе что такое chroot? Или по каким конкретно признакам вы различаете два разных корневых каталога?

Comment: andreymal ну например при команде exit  я выхожу обратно в live

Comment: в общем как я понял пресет должен быть в  /etc/mkinitcpio.d  но там у меня пусто

Comment: Ладно, тогда верю. Но иных предположений у меня не появилось, разве что вы пропустили какую-то ошибку в одной из предыдущих команд, но это уже вам виднее

Comment: andreymal  может флешка как то не так записана, странно но когда я выбираю при хагрузке с флешки efi flash ....  сразу начинает грузится образ винды с той же флешки

Comment: `/etc/mkinitcpio.d` должно быть, тут какая-то опечатка

Answer (score 1):

По этому файлу

```
$ cat /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset 
# mkinitcpio preset file for the 'linux' package

ALL_config="/etc/mkinitcpio.conf"
ALL_kver="/boot/vmlinuz-linux"

PRESETS=('default' 'fallback')

#default_config="/etc/mkinitcpio.conf"
default_image="/boot/initramfs-linux.img"
#default_options=""

#fallback_config="/etc/mkinitcpio.conf"
fallback_image="/boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img"
fallback_options="-S autodetect"
```

Этот файл содержится в пакетах, где-то генерится... Но всеже убедитесь что пакеты `base` и `linux` установленны

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте установить по более современному [туториалу](https://github.com/akimdi/wiki/blob/master/docs/archlinux.md)